# Here is my code when; I run it with xamp a blank page appear

Tags: php, xampp

If I delete `include'classes/actualite.php'` the app runs correctly.  I couldn't solve this problem, so please help me.

```
<?php 
    include'classes/actualite.php' ; 
    $actualite=new actualite();
?>
```

My form code:

```
<form action=""method="post">
        Titre:
        <input type="text" name"titre"><br>
            <textarea name="description"></textarea><br>
            <select>
                <option>Astronomie</option><br>
                <option>Club</option>
            </select>
        </br>Date:
        <input type="date" name="date"></form></section><br>
        Image:
        <input type="file" name="image"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"><br>
    </form>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the source code of the page? Anything in the error logs?

Comment: no error appear :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP's white screen of death](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

Comment: before `include'classes/actualite.php' ;` add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`